# Problem Registering services for DI in NET CORE 3

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, service, asp.net-core-3.0

I am applying dependency injection to my dotnet 3.1 project. I created a class ServiceRegister in my Application layer:

```cs
namespace Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
{
    public static class ServiceRegister
    {
        public static IServiceCollection AddApplicationServices(this IServiceCollection @this)
        {
            // Cart Services
            @this.AddTransient<AddCustomerInformation>();
            @this.AddTransient<AddToCart>();
            @this.AddTransient<GetCart>();
            @this.AddTransient<GetCustomerInformation>();
            @this.AddTransient<Application.Cart.GetOrder>();

            // Orders Services
            @this.AddTransient<CreateOrder>();
            @this.AddTransient<Application.Orders.GetOrder>();

            // Orders Admin Services
            @this.AddTransient<Application.OrdersAdmin.GetOrder>();
            @this.AddTransient<GetOrders>();
            @this.AddTransient<UpdateOrder>();

            // Products Services
            @this.AddTransient<Application.Products.GetProduct>();
            @this.AddTransient<GetProducts>();

            // Products Admin Services
            @this.AddTransient<CreateProduct>();
            @this.AddTransient<DeleteProduct>();
            @this.AddTransient<GetProduct>();
            @this.AddTransient<UpdateProduct>();

            // Stock Admin Services
            @this.AddTransient<CreateStock>();
            @this.AddTransient<DeleteStock>();
            @this.AddTransient<GetStock>();
            @this.AddTransient<UpdateStock>();

            // Users Admin Services
            @this.AddTransient<CreateUser>();

            return @this;
        }
    }
}
```

In my startup class I added:

```
services.AddApplicationServices();
```

When I run the app, the program errors with the following:

```
ArgumentException: Cannot instantiate implementation type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.ISession' for service type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.ISession'
```

In my addCustomerInformation class I have this constructor:

```cs
public class AddCustomerInformation
{
    private readonly ISession _session;

    public AddCustomerInformation(ISession session)
    {
        _session = session;
    }
}
```

I am not an expert in DI, I'm assuming that I also need to register ISession somehow in my serviceRegister class, not sure how should I do that, any clues?? I tried to add this in the register:

this.AddScoped();

But no luck either, it throws an error saying that Session cannot be found, and thats after adding a reference to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http. I'm sure I'm missing something just can't figure it out.

Comment: you can do this. `services.AddScoped<ISession , Session >();`

Comment: Thanks for your reply @viveknuna, when I do that, it cries with the message: Session could not be found, are you missing a directive or assembly reference? Even after I add a reference to using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
It's so weird

Comment: because you have not created a class `Session` that implement the interface`ISession`

Comment: Since its a Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http package, I thought this Session should be already implemented?

Comment: Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.1 if you need to inject session using `AddSession` method.

Answer (score 2):

You should register the dependencies like this:

```
services.AddScoped<IInterface, Implemantation>();
```

You need to specify the `interface` to which you register a specific `implementation`.
You can review the [documantation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1) for more details.

After that you inject the interface like this:

```
public class Service
{
    private readonly IInterface _interface;
    public Service(IInterface interface)
    {
        _interface = interface;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Givko! Well but that is exactly what I'm doing isn't it? I mean, I tried adding services.AddScoped<ISession, Session>(); but the implementation or "Session" lights in red stating that i could not be found. It shows that error wheter I put it in configureServices in startup class and also in ServiceRegister. Not sure whats going on

Comment: I don't see Session and ISession in the code you provided. You must register all of the dependencies which you have shown in your code. I.e.  @this.AddTransient<IAddCustomerInformation, AddCustomerInformation>();

Comment: you can see this article: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: you're absolutelly right, sorry I was following some video series where the guy just missed the Session implementation, and I was thinking that implementation came out of the box with the nuget package, Wrong!! Thank you, learnt something new today ;)